# Using the "Player" package

Tags: ros, logitech, player, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use the "Player" package with a package that I am working on, but I can't seem to find any documentation telling me how to use that package.

Right now, I have "player" listed as a dependency in my manifest.xml file of the package I'm writing, and that's it. Running "cmake ." in the directory doesn't give any errors. Running "make" tells me that it's not finding any Player packages.

Is there something I'm missing in CMakeLists.txt?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10365/using-the-%22player%22-package/) by [xeronia](https://answers.ros.org/users/738/xeronia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2011-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got Player and ROS to integrate without the Player package, with ROS Diamondback and Player 3.0.2.

Instructions are here: http://brice-rebsamen.blogspot.com/2011/05/first-exercise-with-ros-node-to.html

The key is to edit the CMakeLists.txt file so that ROS finds all of the Player libraries that are installed during compilation.

---

Originally posted by [xeronia](https://answers.ros.org/users/738/xeronia/) with karma: 48 on 2011-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to get a camera running with ros, wrapping player is usually *not* the way to go. Instead, you should try to find a ROS driver that supports the camera.

We also have a Logitech Quickcam Orbit/Sphere (vendor/product ID 046d:08b5), and got it running by modifying the [uvc_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera) package. We didn't release it yet because the clean way to go would be to integrate our hack into the uvc_camera package instead of releasing yet another fork.

I've uploaded a snapshot here:

```
git clone http://www.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/mguenthe/git/uos-camera_umd.git
```

**Update:** I've uploaded the current version of the package here: https://github.com/mintar/uos-camera_umd . It runs on Fuerte, Groovy, Hydro. Still a very bad hack. :-)

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2013-11-08**:
Hi Martin, It was nice to meet you at IROS, do you have Orbit driver that can control pan/tilt motor as well?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-11**:
Hi Kei, nice to meet you too! :-)

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-11**:
We've experimented with the Orbit's pan/tilt motor back on player, but got very poor repeatability and so abandoned the idea. I can't find any code related to that any more; but there's a tool called `setpwc` in Debian that allows you to control the motor from the command line.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-11**:
The URL is here: http://www.vanheusden.com/setpwc/

The source code is very short, so it should be easy to wrap that into a ROS driver.

**Comment by [Satoshi Iwashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8741/satoshi-iwashi/) on 2013-11-13**:
unfortunately, setpwc does not work, but guvcview after uvcdynctrl --import=/usr/share/uvcdynctrl/data/046d/logitech.xml
works, thanks!
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=77379

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-11-13**:
Awesome! Since there still seem to be people using this, I've uploaded our hackish driver to Github (see above).